# AEM 6.1 Sightly very basic example from the docs not working

Tags: java, aem, sightly

In the following adobe docs page there is a Sightly Java Use-API example:

http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly/use-api-in-java.html

Neither the first one (without Java) nor the second one (with Java) seems to work for me.

As you can see in the `CRXDE`, for the second example with Java, I have created the `info` component inside the `component` folder with its `info.html` and `Info.java` files inside, with exactly the same content that you can find in the link.

The JSON file is also in its place, inside `content`:

[image]

However, I get a *404 No resource found* error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it wrong. The URL `http://localhost:4502/content/my-example.json` in the docs meant JSON representation of the node `/content/my-example` and not the file `/content/my-example.json`.

What you should actually be doing is

1. Create a node with name `my-example` and type as `nt:unstructured` under `/content`.
2. Add a property `sling:resourceType` whose value points to your component, i.e., `my-example/component/info`.
3. Add properties `title` and `description` with some values so that you can read them in your component.

Now, when you hit `http://localhost:4502/content/my-example.json` in your browser, you would be able to view the JSON representation of your node as shown in the docs.

Accessing the same node with html extension (`http://localhost:4502/content/my-example.html`) would render the output based on the script written within `info.html`.

I would suggest, going through [the Basics](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/the-basics.html) and the [Sling Request Processing Mechanism](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/the-basics.html#Sling%20Request%20Processing) to better understand the above example.